# How to check whether current array element appears in another array's subarray?

Tags: python

Let's say I have 2 arrays:

```
Array A = [['Nov','11-10-2020'],['Jan','01-13-2020'],['Nov','11-11-2020'],['Dec','12-03-2020'],['Jan','01-03-2020'],['Nov','11-03-2020']]

Array B = ['Nov','Jan']
```

Since both `'Nov'` and `'Jan'` appear in array B, I want to

1. compare subarrays in array A has "Nov" and print out the latest date. eg. '11-11-2020'
2. compare subarrays in array A has "Jan" and print out the latest date. eg. '01-13-2020'

May I know how can I do this in python?

Comment: [mm-dd-yyyy](https://starecat.com/aw-look-how-cute-what-a-cute-dog-date-format-oh-no-its-retarded-comic-meme/)

Comment: but how to compare those subarrays in A?

Comment: Try this "
for i in A:
    for x in B:
        if i[0] == x:
            print(x)
            print (i[1])
"

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

Array_A = [['Nov','11-10-2020'],['Jan','01-13-2020'],['Nov','11-11-2020'],['Dec','12-03-2020'],['Jan','01-03-2020'],['Nov','11-03-2020']]

Array_B = ['Nov','Jan']

print (f"Nov: {max([datetime.strptime(x[1], '%m-%d-%Y') for x in Array_A if x[0] in Array_B[0]])}")
print (f"Dec: {max([datetime.strptime(x[1], '%m-%d-%Y') for x in Array_A if x[0] in Array_B[1]])}")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are much better answers here, but i guess this is one way to do it.

```
from datetime import datetime

A = [['Nov','11-10-2020'],['Jan','01-13-2020'],['Nov','11-11-2020'],['Dec','12-03-2025'],['Jan','01-03-2020'],['Nov','11-03-2020']]
B = ['Nov','Jan', 'Dec']
latest_date = datetime.min
for i in range(0, len(A)):
    for j in B:
        if j in A[i]:
            if datetime.strptime(A[i][1], '%m-%d-%Y') > latest_date:
                latest_date = datetime.strptime(A[i][1], '%m-%d-%Y')
latest_date = latest_date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
print(latest_date)
```

Comment: You can write it in two lines with list comprehension :)